# Check if notification has been checked

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript code that displays a notification on the home page of my asp.net website.

There is a function that hides the notification when a user clicks "X"; however, when the user browses to other pages and returns back to the home page, the notification is displayed again.

What's the best way to check if the user has already closed that notification the first time they opened the site? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This could be pretty broad. Is this a sitewide notification that you're only showing once?

Comment: You would need to persist that information somewhere.  (The information that User X has dismissed Notification Y.)  Perhaps a database table of notification/user combinations?  When the user dismisses the notification, update the table to show that it's been read.  When displaying notifications, filter by that table to get rid of the ones which have been read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(assuming "back" is back button)

You can do it via 2 ways ( at least)

1) set a cookie when he clicks the X , then when you back , you can check for a cookie flag.

2) You can check the referrer and if the referrer is Page2 , then reponse.redirect to your self , where you'll loose the code which is saved in cache. youll get a new fresh page

Comment: @downvoter I've done this many times . so your downvote is irrelevant in this case. a state should be saved. a cookie can be reasonable solution. also response redirect to yourself at pageloads , solves it. ( after detecting that request comes from second page)